# DropDownListFor() to specify parent with Self Referencing Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

In my PageModels I have:

```
public class Page : BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PageID { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Page Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Page> Children { get; set; }

    public Page()
    {
        this.Order = 0;
        this.Live = false; 
    }
}

public class CommodityPageMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Page>
{
    public CommodityPageMap()
    {
        HasOptional(x => x.Parent)
            .WithMany(x => x.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

What I want to be able to do is have a drop down in my view that when selected sets the ParentID of my model. I'm not sure how to use `DropDownListFor` that would tie directly to my model.

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `ParentID` is just an integer, so as along as the values in the drop down list are integers that will work just fine.

I guess the question you're really asking then is how to get the list of possible integers for this drop down list?

Your model should have a property which returns that list.  Something as simple as this:

```
public IDictionary<int, string> PossibleParents
{
    get
    {
        // query the database for possible parents
        // return the list of IDs and names
    }
}
```

Then in your view you'd use that property to populate the drop down list:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ParentID, new SelectList(Model.PossibleParents, "Key", "Value"))
```

Comment: Splendid, that is indeed what I meant. Many thanks for your assistance.